# react firestore snapshot not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hi so I followed firebase docs to get data from my collection. But I get error that snapshot is undefined.
This is what I tried:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const db = Firestore.firestore();
        // let tempData = Controller.getData();
        const projects = db.collection('projects');
        const snapshot = projects.get();
        let fireData = [];
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log('data:', doc.data());
            fireData.push(doc.data());
        });

        setData(fireData);
    });
```

[image]
[image]

I tried [TypeError: snapshot.forEach is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59384574/typeerror-snapshot-foreach-is-not-a-function)
But then I het data() is undefined plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`projects.get()` returns a promise that resolves with a QuerySnapshot object.  It doesn't directly return the snapshot.  You have to wait for the promise to resolve in order to get the data, as illustrated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#execute_a_query):

```
        projects.get().then(snapshot => {
          let fireData = [];
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log('data:', doc.data());
            fireData.push(doc.data());
          });
          setData(fireData);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks forgot about promises