# how to trigger a firestore collection via cloud function

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to trigger a new collection (timeline collection) from the existing collection of followers collection and videos collection whenever I clicked the following button in my app.

Now the problem is that, the Cloud Function is created from the view log but the new collection (timeline collection) won't be created.

Below is the code for the Cloud Function where I target the followers collection and the videos collection to create a new timeline collection. I anticipate for your help.

- [Videos collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIlqt.png)
- [Followers collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urbiE.png)
- [Cloud function view logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufRGU.png)

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
    const admin = require("firebase-admin");
    admin.initializeApp();
    
    // // Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
    // // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions
    //
    // exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    //  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
    // });
    exports.onCreateFollower = functions.firestore
      .document("/followers/{userId}/userFollowers/{userfollowerId}")
      .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("The Event has Created The Follower", snapshot.id);
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const userfollowerId = context.params.userfollowerId;
    
        // 1) Create followed users posts ref
        const followedUserVideosCollection = admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("videos")
          .doc(userId)
          .collection("userVideos"); 
    
        // 2) Create following user's timeline ref
        const timelineVideosCollection = admin
          .firestore()
          .collection("timeline")
          .doc(userfollowerId)
          .collection("timelinePosts");
    
        // 3) Get followed users posts
        const querySnapshot = await followedUserVideosCollection.get();
    
        // 4) Add each user post to following user's timeline
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
          if (doc.exists) {
            const videoId = doc.id;
            const videoData = doc.data();
            timelineVideosCollection.doc(videoId).set(videoData);
          }
        });
      });
```

Comment: From the code provided, I can't see where /videos/{userId}/userVideos are written. Could you perhaps add where that happens?

Comment: I was trying to target the user followerID from the followers collection i.e if i am following a user,  I should be able to see all the videos he or she posted in my timeline collection,  So i target the followersID from the followers collection to get all its video from the videos Collection i.e all the videos the followersID posted to the video collection.  Hope you understand. Please help me. The cloud functions created but doesn't created the timeline collection. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any error on your Cloud Functions log whenever the function is triggered?

Comment: I didn't noticed the image you've provided. I've tried editing the question now.

Comment: Alright, waiting.....

Comment: What's a sample data inside `userVideos` subcollection? I don't see it on your image

Comment: It's not existing on your Firestore DB, and `userId` may not match as a document name, so the snapshot doesn't exist, skipping step 4.

Comment: Thanks alot,  let me skipped step 4 and get back to you.

Comment: Nothing is working, I have tried all my best. When I removed the userVideos collection,  I got error in the Cloud functions view log that quarySnapshot.forEach isn't a function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what causes the error "querySnapshot.forEach isn't a function". According [to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59384687/7031308), you need to query the collection first because `get()` returns a document instead of a snapshot. Here's a sample code (see step 3):

```
// 1) Create followed users posts ref
const followedUserVideosCollection = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("videos")
    .doc("Videos 1") // I changed the value with your sample for test purposes and also because I'm not sure how you fill up this doc.
    .collection("userVideos");

// 2) Create following user's timeline ref
const timelineVideosCollection = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection("timeline")
    .doc(userfollowerId)
    .collection("timelinePosts");

// 3) Get followed users posts & Add each user post to following user's timeline
await followedUserVideosCollection.where('id', '==', 0).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
    if (querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            if (doc) {
                const videoId = doc.id;
                const videoData = doc.data();
                timelineVideosCollection.doc(videoId).set(videoData);
            }
        });
    }else {
        console.log("Document not found");
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

A solution is to create a filter, and make sure that the document you're looking for matches the filter. For example, a document inside the subcollection `userVideos` should have a field called `id` with value of 0.

You may have to remodel your DB to fix the line where I put a comment but this code should write the `timeline` collection.

Comment: Thanks alot,  the code didn't trigger the timeline collection even after I modified the videos collection by adding the user videos subcollection with the userId.